# Como obtengo los datos de una consulta join en ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo esta consulta

```
@permiso = Permiso.joins(:importador).joins(:producto)
```

Ahora necesito obtener los datos en variables para poder trabajar con ellos

Actualmente los obtengo de esta manera, necesito saber cúal es la manera correcta de hacerlo.

```
<% @permiso.each do |permiso| %>
   <%= permiso.id %>
   <%= permiso.fecha_emision %>
   <%= permiso.producto.nombre %>
   <%= permiso.importador.telefono %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: ¿a que te refieres con manera correcta? ¿te da algún problema de la manera en que lo estás haciendo actualmente? Replantea tu pregunta, porque no veo lo malo en lo que haces actualmente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a asumir que por "¿cuál es la manera correcta de hacerlo? te refieres a la más efectiva desde el punto de vista del uso de memoria y cantidad de queries a la base de datos.

**Respuesta:**
Mi recomendación sería:

```
@permisos = Permiso.includes(:importador, :producto).all
```

**¿Por qué?**
El objetivo debería ser hacer la cantidad mínima de queries y guardar la cantidad mínima de datos en la memoria.

Cuando no usas *joins* ni *includes* y luego utilizas datos de las tablas asociadas en la vista estarás causando el famoso problema de N+1 Query. Es decir, causando una query (o 2 en tu caso) adicional por cada dato asociado que cargues en la vista. Esto es especialmente grave cuanto más largo es el listado. En tu ejemplo, cada vez que tu *each* muestra *permiso.producto.nombre* y *permiso.importador.telefono* estaría golpeando nuevamente la base de datos. Salvo que estés haciendo *Russian Doll Caching* (no creo que sea el caso) es tu peor escenario desde el punto de vista de performance.

Cuando haces un *joins* como en tu caso, estarás filtrando los datos de *permisos* que tengan *importador* y *producto* asociados. Y el joins puede utilizar dichas tablas para afinar más tu query. Por ejemplo podrías hacer:

```
@productos = Producto.joins(:importador).where(importador: {activo: true}) # La query es inventada obviamente porque no conozco tu tabla
```

*joins* utiliza las tablas asociadas para la query, pero no carga la información en la memoria. Y estaría perfecto si NO quieres usar esos datos luego. Pero en tu caso sí los usas y por lo tanto NO estás evitando el problema del N+1. Esto lo podrás verificar viento tus logs.

Nos queda la opción de *includes*. Includes si reduce la cantidad de queries y sí carga todo en la memoria. En tu caso tendrías solo 3 queries. Sin duda será la mejor opción desde el punto de vista de performance.

Un par de aclaraciones importantes:

1. Si quieres solamente tener resultados de permisos que tengan un importador y un producto asociado deberías agregar también un *joins* para asegurarte que haga un *INNER JOIN*
2. Cambié el nombre de tu variable a @permisos. Te recomiendo usar un plural siempre que tengas una colección de datos para evitar confusiones.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaracion, si de echo lo que quería evitar eran los miles de querys que veia en el log

Comment: Me alegra @Daniel-00000. Si contestó tu pregunta seleccionala como respuesta para que no quede abierta.

Answer (score -2):

Si lo que deseas es mostrar la información como la tienes en tu ejemplo entonces no es necesario que haga la consulta de los joins.

De echo podrías hacerlo de la siguiente forma y seguiría funcionando perfectamente

`@permisos = Permiso.all`

Y en la vista exactamente como lo tienes y no deberías tener ningún problema.

En los casos en lo que te sería útil el `join` si seria tuvieras alguna condicional y solo tuvieras los valores de otra de las tablas, por ejemplo que quisieran encontrar los permiso según el importador y el producto.

`@permiso = Permiso.joins(:importador, :producto).where(importador:{name:'Importador 1'}, producto:{precio:'15'})`

Comment: No lo creo, el método all solo trae los datos de una tabla, los joins trabajan con más de una tabla relacionada

Comment: -1 tu respuesta es incorrecta

Comment: pues de hecho si lees su consulta vas a ver que si usa 2 tablas por lo cual el join al menos aqui si es útil y el método `all` no

Comment: Si, eso es lo que hace el método all. Pero ActiveRecord te permite llamar las relaciones. Por ello la importancia de en el modelo agregar el has_many, has_one, belongs_to, etc. Eso métodos al tenerlo el modelo te genera método de acceso a las relaciones del objeto. Si no me crees podrías intentarlo desde la consola de rails.  `permiso = Permiso.all`, 
`permiso[0].importador`   y te aseguro que te va funcionar. Y yo insisto que para la forma en que quiere mandar a llamar la información no es necesario usar el join

Comment: no es el hecho de que no te crea, se como funciona eso; el asunto es que no sabes si el OP esta manejando así las relaciones o quiere escribir el SQL directo sin necesidad de ellos; es por eso importante que seas claro que debe usar y bajo que condiciones

Comment: Tienes razón, no sé lo que quiere hacer y no si esté utilizando las relaciones de esa forma, pero la verdad debería hacerlo, le facilitaría mucho sus consultas. Ademas de que la pregunta está un poco incompleta. Porque realmente no describe el problema que tiene. Yo solo quise aportarle un poco de lo que a mi me parece.